# adjusting conditions under which openssh does key re-exchange?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Quoting [RFC4253 The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol § Section 9 - Key Re-Exchange](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4253#section-9),

> It is RECOMMENDED that the keys be changed after each gigabyte of transmitted data or after each hour of connection time, whichever comes sooner.

My question is...  is there a way I can change this with OpenSSH Server / sshd_config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `RekeyLimit`
> Specifies the maximum amount of data that may be transmitted before the session key is renegotiated, optionally followed by a maximum amount of time that may pass before the session key is renegotiated. The first argument is specified in bytes and may have a suffix of `K`, `M`, or `G` to indicate Kilobytes, Megabytes, or Gigabytes, respectively. The default is between `1G` and `4G`, depending on the cipher. The optional second value is specified in seconds and may use any of the units documented in the TIME FORMATS section. The default value for RekeyLimit is `default none`, which means that rekeying is performed after the cipher's default amount of data has been sent or received and no time based rekeying is done.

Source: [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#RekeyLimit).

`RekeyLimit` can be used by a client as well (see [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#RekeyLimit)).